# App Crashes (Sometimes) when Home Button is Pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I am really confused as to why this is happening.

Since this happened randomly

Here is the stacktrace, I have not been able to figure it out.

Please help

Thanks

```
2015-03-30 15:12:50.817 MarcoApp[1857:23629] -[NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint finishedLoading]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f929ccc8cf0
2015-03-30 15:12:50.908 MarcoApp[1857:23629] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint finishedLoading]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f929ccc8cf0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa74a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a333bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa7bd1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9d39dc ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9d3578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa447fc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a944204 _CFXNotificationPost + 2484
7   Foundation                          0x0000000109e8ddf8 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
8   UIKit                               0x000000010b73baa7 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDectivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 1054
9   UIKit                               0x000000010b748833 __88-[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 87
10  UIKit                               0x000000010b7487cd -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 349
11  UIKit                               0x000000010b73345a -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 486
12  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001115ae243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9a9c7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a99f9c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a99f785 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a99ebc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e89ca58 GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x000000010b735580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
19  MarcoApp                           0x0000000109184afe top_level_code + 78
20  MarcoApp                           0x0000000109184bda main + 42
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ee2b145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell without seeing your code but "unrecognized selector sent to instance" implies you have a method the requires a selector (name of a function) as a parameter and that methods got an invalid selector (the name of the function is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

not sure but ther is any method in

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

which does not have selector thats why you app crash